# Windows 8.1 - unfixable grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, grub-efi

I have a Gigabyte laptop that came with secure boot and windows 8. 
After a bit of battling, I managed to get my dual boot with Ubuntu 13.10..

Anyway, I upgraded zindows to 8.1, now grub is gone. 
I restarted from a live CD and chrooted to my drive. I used boot-repair multiple times (with successful output) both in default and with some advanced options; also reinstalled grub manually... Each time it tries once to boot to grub but gives a message for a very short amount of time. I recorded it and it is a regular bios message "Rebbot and Select proper Boot device of Insert Boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

I even tried something called EasyBCD under winblows, it shows the correct boot options, but same there, it is unable to make the linux partition fire up.

Anyway, no way to boot my linux box. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? No need to redirect me to another post with grub reinstall or boot-repair, seen them all...
I am thinking of trying this other boot loader, refind, to see if it works http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html
Also re-reading this bios message, I'm thinking my partition might not have a boot flag anymore... I'll try that too with parted. Although both grub and win 8 are supposed to fire up from the same boot partition (the EFI one)

Please help! 
thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [disabling Secure Boot?](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) If not, do so. If that doesn't help, go ahead and install rEFInd from Windows, or try using the rEFInd USB flash drive or CD-R. (The latter is safer, in that it won't write anything to your hard disk or modify your NVRAM settings, so if it doesn't work there won't be any non-functional stuff left behind.) Note that rEFInd requires [extra configuration](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) to work with Secure Boot, so if you want to use rEFInd with Secure Boot enabled, you'll need to jump through those extra hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on the Windows side to point back the the Windows boot record.

Use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the Ubuntu side to point the grub location. If you cannot get the system to boot the local installation natively, boot it from a Live Ubuntu installer image and run boot-repair from that.